# Pythonic way of obtaining serial correlation of elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, -5, 2], [2, -4, -4], [3, 3, 1], [-4, 2, -2], [-5, 1, 4]],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

In a pythonic way, how can I obtain the serial correlation of consecutive elements of the column pairwise. The serial correlation is simple:

For example for the first to elements of column A:

If element `1A > 0 & 2A > 0 or 1A < 0 & 2A < 0 Serial Correlation = 1`

If element `1A > 0 & 2A < 0 or 1A < 0 & 2A > 0 Serial Correlation = -1`

And you would go down the column comparing each element to the previous.

The desired output with our dummy df.

```
   A  B  C
1        
2  1  1 -1
3  1 -1 -1
4 -1  1 -1
5  1  1 -1
```

Then I would do something like `serial_corr = df.mean()`, to get the total s.correlation for the column.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `DataFrame's` `shift` method. Note: this will produce NaN if either of the values being compared is 0.

```
result = (A.shift() * A).dropna()
result /= result.abs()
print(result)
```

produces

```
   A  B  C
2  1  1 -1
3  1 -1 -1
4 -1  1 -1
5  1  1 -1
```

Comment: Very very nice. Thanks